# "Gum Arabic" vs. "Arabic Gum"

Tags: grammar

As far as I know, adjectives modify nouns. So we can say "American gum", "Australian gum", etc. Why then do we say "gum Arabic" instead of "Arabic gum" ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think [Gum Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gum_arabic) is totally different from [gum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_gum).

Comment: It can be explained in [one word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uj0KwNfLUds).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we call it "gum arabic" and not "arabic gum"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196255/why-do-we-call-it-gum-arabic-and-not-arabic-gum)

Answer (score 2):

*[Gum Arabic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/gum-arabic?q=gum%20arabic)* (also *gum arabic*) is the gum or sap of some kinds of acacia trees.

The *Oxford English Dictionaty* defines it as

> A water-soluble gum exuded by certain acacias (esp. Acacia senegal), used in the food and cosmetics industries and in glue and incense.

The reason it is *gum arabic* and not *arabic gum* is presumably due to at least two things:

1 It is referred to in other languages as *gumme arabic* (French), *gomma arabica* (Italian), *gommi Arabicum* (Latin). So it seems English writers chose to use the word with the noun *gum* first followed by the adjective.

2 There are dozens of other such *gums* such as *[gum olibanum](http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/gum-olibanum.html)*, also known as *[frankincense](http://www.alfarid.org/Products/gums/frankincence-olibanum-boswellia-occult.html)*, in which the noun comes first.

The kind of ***gum*** that you chew is short for *[chewing gum](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/chewing-gum?q=chewing%20gum)*. So you could refer to some as 'American (chewing) gum', 'Australian (chewing) gum' and even 'Arabian (chewing) gum'.

Note: *Arabian* is the adjective that has much broader usage, as in *Arabian knights*, *Arabian horses*, *Arabian coffee*, *Arabian mustard*, etc., whereas 'Arabic' usually refers to the language, writing or numbers (*ie* 'arabic numerals').

Thanks to the *OED online* for much of this information.

Comment: Thank you. Your first reason seems absolutely convincing .